# How does the MapReduce master process decide which task to be assigned to a single worker process?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

This question is not going to discuss the specific case in Hadoop or Spark.

When I was reading [MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf), I was confused about

> The master picks idle workers and assigns each one a map task or a
>   reduce task.

So how does the master decide whether a worker should get a Map task or Reduce task?
If we only assign reduce tasks first, will we never have the job done? (Because no Map task will be completed)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is required to be ran only after the data needed from the map and shuffle stages are complete.

In the context of Hadoop implementation of MapReduce, map tasks are decided based on data locality, otherwise, any open resources, as decided by YARN, are chosen